# How to calculate the quotient and the reminder when $F=\mathbb Z_5[x],f(x)=3x+1,g(x)=x^3+2x+1?$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

Division Algorithm says that, for any field $F$ and for $f(x),g(x)(\neq 0)\in F[x]$$~\exists$ unique $q(x),r(x)\in F[x]$ such that $f(x)=g(x)q(x)+r(x)$ where $\deg r(x)<\deg g(x)$ or $r(x)=0.$

I'm having trouble in finding such $q(x),r(x)$ when $\deg g(x)>\deg f(x)$ e.g. how to calculate the quotient and the reminder when $F=\mathbb Z_5[x],f(x)=3x+1,g(x)=x^3+2x+1?$

Thanking you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you get $f(x)=g(x)\cdot 0 + f(x)$, so $q(x)=0$, and $r(x)=f(x)$. In the particular case you mention: $(3x+1)=(x^3+2x+1)\cdot 0 + 3x+1$, so that $q(x)=0$ and $r(x)=3x+1$.